# Java Applet not loading in webbrowser control on windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, applet, webbrowser-control

A simple java applet is to be loaded from another device on my desktop application web browser control on windows 10 (64 bit). This java applet is working fine with IE 11 (with compatibility settings on) on the windows 10 machine but when this is loaded in web browser control (WPF app on .net framework 4.0 and with "Any CPU" build settings) there is a cross on the upper left corner and java applet doesn't load. Also if the WPF app build setting is "x86" the WPF app crashes while trying to load applet.

The same applet is working without any problem with IE 8.0 on windows xp (32 bit) within webbrowser control of WPF application.

Also we won't be able to modify the java applet within the device as device is already in field.

Comment: Is is possible to provide more error details?

Comment: unhandled exception was encountered during a user callback. I guess the exception occured in user32.dll (this is in case of 32 bit app)